Request for reference to an old case - Svensk juristidining, 47 (1962) 17-32, cited in Zeisel
I'm reading an article ''Trial by mathematics: precision and ritual in the legal process'' by L. Tribe published in Harvard Law Review 1971 April (link). It mentions in page 1340 an interesting Swedish case from 1960's about booking for overtime parking. The reference for this is as below

Parkeringsfrägor, II. Tillförlitligheten av det S.K. lock systemet för
parkeringskontroll. Svensk juristidining, 47 (1962) 17-32, cited in
Zeisel, supra note 31, at 12.

After using online translation to English, it turns out to be,

Parking issues, II. The reliability of the S.K. the lid system for
parking control. Svensk juristidining, 47 (1962) 17-32, cited in
Zeisel, supra note 31, at 12.

I am interested in knowing more about this case. When I searched on the internet, I could not find anything. I also do not read or write Swedish. So, any help about any reference on this case, preferably in English, or otherwise in Swedish, will be much appreciated.
If this is not the right forum to ask this, I can take this down.

This isn't an inappropriate forum to ask this, but it is reasonably likely that a Swedish case from 1962 is only available in hard copy form, or only through a paid subscription to a Swedish legal research site, and is not available in full text on the Internet for free. I don't know one way or the other.

I don't speak any Swedish but I tried to use some research skills. Tribe's citation contains several mistakes, common to other citing sources in English, but once past that we have a better picture of the source. I'm not currently physically close to a library that has a copy, but your friendly local librarian might be able to help you if you wish to track down an original, on the basis of the corrected reference below.
An English-language summary appears in the International Encyclopedia of the Social Sciences (1968 ed.) in its entry  on "Statistics as Legal Evidence":

One of the normal functions of a legal trial is to resolve an uncertain factual situation according to some canon of probability: in criminal cases by evidence that establishes guilt "beyond reasonable doubt," in civil cases by a "preponderance of the evidence." In spite of these probabilistic terms, the law "refuses to honor its own formula when the evidence is coldly 'statistical.': As a rule, "probabilities are determined in a most subjective and unscientific way" (Hart & McNaughton 1958, p. 54). [...] However, in a recent Swedish trial for overtime parking, a figure was put to what constitutes insufficient probability for a finding of "guilty." The police constable had marked the position of the valves on two tires on a standard sketch, accurate to the nearest "hour," one valve at the "1 o'clock" position and the other at the "12 o'clock" position. Returning after a time lapse greater than the permitted length of parking, the constable found both valves in the same positions they had been in earlier. The defendant claimed he had left the place and returned. The Court of Appeals considered odds of (12 x 12 = ) 144:1 insufficient and declared registering the position of all four tire valves would have been sufficient—odds of (124 = ) 20,736:1 ("Parkeringsfrägor ..." 1962, pp. 24, 25). The court may be pardoned for having overstated the odds by calculating them under the assumption that the positions of the valve markings are statistically independent of each other, which is almost certainly not true.

The first citation is to the book Evidence and Inference in the Law (1958) by Henry M. Hart Jr. and John T. McNaughton, and the second is to the report we are interested in. The account here basically matches what Tribe says in his paper.
The periodical is Svensk juristtidning, which has an online archive going back to 1962 and beyond. Alas, the 1962 volume there does not seem to have anything to do with parking on the page numbers mentioned. I believe the citation is to the "rättsfall" (law report) supplement instead, which appears to not be included in the archive. The International Encyclopedia of Comparative Law says that this journal published law reports from the Courts of Appeal ("rättsfall från hovrätterna") prior to 1980 when the courts themselves took over the job (entry for "Sweden" by Åke Malmström, section II.4 "Publications").
A thematic index of the journal's law reports does have an entry for:

Parkeringsfrågor. I. Tillförlitligheten av parkeringsmätare. II. Tillförlitligheten av det s. k. klocksystemet för parkeringskontroll.

in the year 1962, page 21. So the title as cited by Tribe has some typos: a "clock system" rather than a "lock system"; "s. k." = "så kallad" = "so-called" shouldn't be in capitals as if it were a proper name; "frågor" has an å in it rather than an ä; and "parkernigskontroll" should be "parkeringskontroll". Also, the journal title has "tidning" not "tidining". Many other English-language references to the report seem to reproduce some or all of these errors.
A later cross-reference in the main journal,

I SvJT 1962 rf s. 21 uppkom spörsmål om tillförlitligheten av parkeringsmätare (I) och tillförlitligheten av det s. k. klocksystemet för parkeringskontroll.
In SvJT 1962 rf s. 21 questions arose about the reliability of parking meters (I) and the reliability of the so-called clock system for parking control. [Google Translate]

gives no more clues on the content but does confirm the spellings and the "rf" for "rättsfall" for the citation.
It's hard to anticipate the level of detail that the original report might have, but it would likely have more context on the procedural history of the case (e.g. where and when this happened, which courts took it up). Other general sources on Swedish law would be more useful for understanding how disputed facts are to be proved. The IESS entry talks about "beyond reasonable doubt" and "preponderance of the evidence", which are Anglo-American terms: it's not immediately obvious what standard would apply to a 1960s parking fine in Sweden. I would be cautious about accepting Tribe's statement that "reasonable doubt" was the standard here, without checking the original sources and the precise term used in Swedish.

I can't thank you enough. Truly appreciate your help here.
